# Execute a function in a specific second in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, timer

I'm making a backup scheduler of my files, using a `Timer`, and it executes when the said time is equal to the current time, But my problem is it keeps on executing until 1 sec has passed like what i do when i use `MsgBox`.

This is what i have tried and it's not working, it still executes until 1 second has passed. Please help me achieve that. Thanks!

```
Dim d As Date = DateTime.Now
Dim d1 As Date = d.AddMilliseconds(1)
Dim dw As String = d1 & DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString
Dim date2 As Date = cntrl.Value.AddMilliseconds(1)

If Form3.chkWed.Checked = True Then
     If dw = date2 & Form3.chkWed.Text Then
         CopyStart(src, dest)
     End If
End If
If Form3.chkThu.Checked = True Then
      If dw = date2 & Form3.chkThu.Text Then
          MsgBox("P")
      End If
End If
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for.  Are you saying that the task doesn't start until 1 second after the specified time and you want it to start immediately?  If not, I have no idea at all what you mean.

Comment: The task starts exactly at the specified time, but it keeps running until that second is not finished because of its milisecond, because my `DateTimePicker`'s value is `H:MM:SS`, I'm planning for it to execute at exactly let's say 1.5 sec so it **NOT** will keep running from 1sec - 2sec. i.e. the task starts at `1:01:5:` then it's still running until `1:01:6`, it should be running once.

Comment: So you're saying that the task starts multiple times then, yes? If that's the case then it would appear to be a bad implementation because if you're using a Timer then you should just start the task once when the `Timer` raises a `Tick` event.  Why are you raising the `Tick` event multiple times per second if you only want to start the task once?

Comment: Yep, Do I need 2 `Timer`s with that? Because i have multiple checkboxes, can you give me a sample code please?

Comment: The `Timer` should have its `Interval` set such that it raises a `Tick` event when you next need to start a task.  There's no need to do any checking because you know that the task is to start when a `Tick` is raised.  You would set the `Interval` when any of the `CheckBox` controls is checked or unchecked.  At that point you can work out exactly how long it will be until the next task and you set the `Interval` accordingly.  When the task is done, you determine when the next task will be and set the `Interval` accordingly again.  It's like an alarm clock.

Comment: I'm done with `Interval`s and it's not applicable for my program (or just lack of knowledge =D), But thanks for your idea that solved my problem, I used two `Timers` but the task runs now after 1 sec delay how could that be?, But it runs once now. Thanks!

Comment: @Dhan - You're really going to have a problem with getting any kind of timer to get down to the `1ms` resolution. The standard timers have a `15ms` resolution, so if you ask for one to fire at `1ms` it'll take up to `15ms` longer than that to fire.

Comment: This is what comes from writing code before determining logic.  The logic is simple. Whenever the user performs an action that might change when the next task is to start, you work out when that next task is to start and you set the `Interval` of your one `Timer` such that it will `Tick` at that time.  If you don't know how to work out when the next task has to start then that is what you should be spending time considering instead of working out how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm talking about is something like the following.  In this example, there are three `RadioButton` controls that indicate that a task should be initiated at 1.00 PM, 5.00 PM and 9.00 PM respectively.

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    'The next task is to start at 1.00 PM
    Me.ResetTimerInterval(TimeSpan.FromHours(13))
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    'The next task is to start at 5.00 PM
    Me.ResetTimerInterval(TimeSpan.FromHours(17))
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
    'The next task is to start at 9.00 PM
    Me.ResetTimerInterval(TimeSpan.FromHours(21))
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'The next task will start in 24 hours.
    With Me.Timer1
        .Stop()
        .Interval = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromHours(24).TotalMilliseconds)
        .Start()
    End With

    'Start a task right now.
    Me.InitiateTask()
End Sub

Private Sub ResetTimerInterval(nextTaskStartTime As TimeSpan)
    Dim nextTaskStartDateTime = Date.Today + nextTaskStartTime

    If Date.Now > nextTaskStartDateTime Then
        nextTaskStartDateTime.AddDays(1)
    End If

    Dim timeUntilNextTask = nextTaskStartDateTime - Date.Now

    With Me.Timer1
        .Stop()
        .Interval = Convert.ToInt32(timeUntilNextTask.TotalMilliseconds)
        .Start()
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub InitiateTask()
    '...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added another `Timer`, and did something like this.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

Dim dw As String = DateTime.Now & DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString
     If Form3.chkThu.Checked = True Then
        If dw = Form3.DateTimePicker1.Value & Form3.chkThu.Text Then
            Timer2.Enabled = True
        End If
     End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

Timer2.Enabled = False
     MsgBox("P")
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a solution to the wrong problem.  If you worked on the right problem then you would end up with a better solution.